# Specify in Kubernetes deployment that image must be run in interactive mode

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an image that needs to be run in interactive mode (or else I get `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`).

```
docker run -i imagename
```

Everything works fine when I run it in interactive mode but how do I specify that in the deployment YAML file?

My YAML looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stackoverflow
spec:
  replicas: 2
  minReadySeconds: 15
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stackoverflow
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: stackoverflow
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: stackoverflow
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works fine when I run it in interactive mode but how do I specify that

- in our statefusets (should work for deployments as well) we use following:

  ```
  ...
  containers:
    - image: stackoverflow
      name: stackoverflow
      stdin: true
      tty: true
      ...
  ```

  note that `docker` flag `-i` corresponds to `stdin`, and flag `-t` to `tty` in container specification.

As requested, here is [v1.10 documentation reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core) for container spec:

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, could you point me to the documentation that says which parameters can be used in the container spec?

Comment: Sure, answer is updated with requested container spec documentation.